# "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page"

Tags: javascript, html

Below Is my code I keep getting the You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page error.

I have used a google weather overlay and a Custom Marker overlay

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #panel {
          
          position: absolute;
          top: 5px;
          left: 50%;
          margin-left: -500px;
          z-index: 5;
          background-color: transparent;
          padding: 5px;
          //border: 1px solid #999;
      }
    </style>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=AIzaSyD2ldpYgQrMTO6w9k-f9x0FhKlnB7n6pQ03.exp"></script>
    
   
    <script type ="text/javascript" src ="Assignment.js"> </script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=weather&sensor=true_or_false"></script> 
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=drawing"></script>
  

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="panel">
     
    <button type="button" onclick="setHYB()">Hybrid Mode</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="setRoad()">Road Mode</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="zoomTo()">Choose Your Location</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="zoomIn()">Zoom In</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="zoomOut()">Zoom Out</button>
    <button type="button" id="weather" >Weather On or Off</button>   
    <button type="button" onclick="addMarker()">Add your own Marker</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="clearMarkers()">Clear Own Markers</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="showMarkers()">Show Markers</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="deleteMarkers()">Delete Markers</button>

   
    </div>
      
      <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Have I done something wrong?
Have I missed anything?

Comment: Well, you included it 3 times...

Comment: What sections do I have to remove because they have different uses

Comment: It is the same script. You are re-loading the whole api to pass a new parameter every time.  Just concatenate the parameters: `<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=AIzaSyD2ldpYgQrMTO6w9k-f9x0FhKlnB7n6pQ03.exp&sensor=true&v=3.exp&libraries=weather"></script>`

Answer (score -1):

Here you need indicate true or false no true_false

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=weather&sensor=true_or_false"></script>
```

Comment: I am getting a lot of conflict with the scripts with the rest of the code . For example if i Remove      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=drawing"></script>     the weather layer works.